# Invalid column name 'User_User_Id'. Invalid column name 'Group_Group_Id'. EF6 Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM Project on net461 framework running Class Library 4.6.1, the class library has data access repositories running EF 6.1.

i am getting the following errors:
Invalid column name 'User_User_Id'.
Invalid column name 'Group_Group_Id'.

When call the following repository code:

```
public ReviewWorkflow GetWorkflowWithActors(int reviewWorkflowId)
    {
        return DbContext.ReviewWorkflows.Include(a => a.ReviewWorkflowActors).Where( r => r.ReviewWorkflow_Id == reviewWorkflowId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Entities

```
public partial class ReviewWorkflow
{
    public ReviewWorkflow()
    {
        this.ReviewWorkflowActors = new List<ReviewWorkflowActor>();
        this.ReviewWorkflowsProjects = new List<ReviewWorkflowsProject>();
    }

    public int ReviewWorkflow_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public int Owner_UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReviewWorkflowActor> ReviewWorkflowActors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReviewWorkflowsProject> ReviewWorkflowsProjects { get; set; }

    public ReviewWorkflowView TransformToReviewWorkflowView()
    {
        return new ReviewWorkflowView()
        {
            Name = this.Name,
            ReviewWorkflowActors = this.ReviewWorkflowActors.Select(r => r.TransformToReviewWorkflowActor()).ToList()
        };
    }
}


 public partial class ReviewWorkflowActor
{
    public int ReviewWorkflowActor_Id { get; set; }
    public int ReviewWorkflow_Id { get; set; }
    public byte SequenceNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Group_Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> User_Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public  ReviewWorkflow ReviewWorkflow { get; set; }

    public ReviewWorkflowActorView TransformToReviewWorkflowActor()
    {
        return new ReviewWorkflowActorView() {
            Group_Id = this.Group_Id,
            SequenceNo =  this.SequenceNo,
            User_Id = this.User_Id
        };
    }
}
```

Map:

```
public class ReviewWorkflowMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ReviewWorkflow>
{
    public ReviewWorkflowMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ReviewWorkflow_Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(1000);

        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.UpdateBy)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.RowVersion)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ReviewWorkflows", "Weekly");
        this.Property(t => t.ReviewWorkflow_Id).HasColumnName("ReviewWorkflow_Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate");
        this.Property(t => t.UpdateBy).HasColumnName("UpdateBy");
        this.Property(t => t.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName("UpdatedDate");
        this.Property(t => t.RowVersion).HasColumnName("RowVersion");
        this.Property(t => t.Owner_UserId).HasColumnName("Owner_UserId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.ReviewWorkflows)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Owner_UserId);

    }
}


public class ReviewWorkflowActorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ReviewWorkflowActor>
{
    public ReviewWorkflowActorMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ReviewWorkflowActor_Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.UpdateBy)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.RowVersion)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ReviewWorkflowActors", "Weekly");
        this.Property(t => t.ReviewWorkflowActor_Id).HasColumnName("ReviewWorkflowActor_Id");
        this.Property(t => t.ReviewWorkflow_Id).HasColumnName("ReviewWorkflow_Id");
        this.Property(t => t.SequenceNo).HasColumnName("SequenceNo");
        this.Property(t => t.Group_Id).HasColumnName("Group_Id");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Id).HasColumnName("User_Id");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate");
        this.Property(t => t.UpdateBy).HasColumnName("UpdateBy");
        this.Property(t => t.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName("UpdatedDate");
        this.Property(t => t.RowVersion).HasColumnName("RowVersion");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.ReviewWorkflow)
            .WithMany(t => t.ReviewWorkflowActors)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ReviewWorkflow_Id);

    }
}
```

Others:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EFDbConfiguration))]
public class EWRSContext : DbContext
{
    public EWRSContext()
        : base(_connectionString)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    public  DbSet<Murad> Muradies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PositionHierarchy> PositionHierarchy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrganizationHierarchy> OrganizationHierarchy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Delegation> Delegations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GroupPermission> GroupPermissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GroupUser> GroupUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NotificationsUser> NotificationsUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectStatus> ProjectStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReviewWorkflowInstance> ReviewWorkflowInstances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReviewWorkflow> ReviewWorkflows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReviewWorkflowsProject> ReviewWorkflowsProjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubjectStatus> SubjectStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeamModel> TeamModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeamModelSubject> TeamModelSubjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WeeklyInput> WeeklyInputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WeeklyInputHistory> WeeklyInputHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BusinessUnitesView> BusinessUnitesViews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        //Murad :: Fluent API configuration goes here
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PositionHierarchyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrganizationHierarchyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DelegationMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupPermissionMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupUserMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PermissionMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConfigurationMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NotificationMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NotificationsUserMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectStatusMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReviewWorkflowInstanceMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReviewWorkflowMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReviewWorkflowsProjectMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubjectMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubjectStatusMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeamModelMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeamModelSubjectMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TemplateMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WeeklyInputMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WeeklyInputHistoryMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BusinessUnitesViewMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MuradConfigurationMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReviewWorkflowActorMap());

    }

    //Add Db Custom validation Errors
    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        //validate Project Data Insertion
        if (entityEntry.Entity is Project && (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added || entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified))
        {
            var dbErrors = new ProjectValidator().Validate(entityEntry);
            if (dbErrors != null)
                return dbErrors;
        }


        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);

    }


}
```

Comment: I believe you are hitting a ShadowProperty and since you do have 2 Properties as `Nullable<int>` that relate to the respective types I believe EFC is saying where are they on the table, cause it thinks they are suppose to be there.  Did you try using the DbContext creation tools from your existing DB with EFC?  Package manager Console commands  has them https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/powershell.html#scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: Remember no lazy or explicit loading so it also might be missing other stuff that is necessary so Include / ThenInclude (might be necessary).

Comment: i am sorry i am new to EF6, i do not access any shadow property, i used ef power tool for VS 2015 (after modification) to generate my context.

Comment: which are you using cause your title says EF Core which is NOT EF6

Comment: What title you refer to, my title saying ef6 explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever you are trying to do it appears its related to the RelationShip associated with

`public User User { get; set; }`

in `ReviewWorkflow`

and in `ReviewWorkflowActor`

with

`public Nullable<int> Group_Id { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> User_Id { get; set; }`   <--- Main Issue its trying to map through convention

these 2 nullables are your present issue since it doesn't know where Group_Id is coming from nor User_Id it doesn't know how to map these 2 columns to columns in your tables, since they don't exist in your 2 tables shown.

EF doesn't know how to resolve them hence your error, the relationship probably related to foreignkey issues, it also may have to do with Groups/Users tables.